# How to fit a time series mixed model with several random effect in R (nmle)?

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I need to fit a time series mixed model in nmle. I found that nlme allows to specify the heterogeneous structure of the variance. My response variable is yield, which is dependent on

- fixed factors: Genotype + Table + Genotype x Week  + Table x Week + Akima (Akima is fit as a covariate)
- Random factors: Col + Row + Col x Week + Row x Week
- Repeated factor: measurements every "Week" per "Plant"

So far, I have fit the fixed and random factors, and it works.

```
data$Plant <- as.factor(data$Plant)
data$Week <- as.factor(data$Week)
data$Table <- as.factor(data$Table)
data$Block <- as.factor(data$Block)
data$Row <- as.factor(data$Row)
data$Col <- as.factor(data$Col)
data$Genotype <- as.factor(data$Genotype)

data$br <- with(data, Row:Week)
data$bc <- with(data, Col:Week)


# Only random variables
model1 <- lme(Yield ~ Genotype + Table + Genotype:Week  + Table:Week + Akima,
              random = list(Col=~ 1, Row=~ 1, br=~ 1, bc=~ 1),
              data = data)
```

The issue appears when I try to add the repeated variable. The variance-covariance matrix I have decided for the repeated factor is the UNSTRUCTURED one.

```
model2 <- lme(Yield ~ Genotype + Table + Genotype:Week  + Table:Week + Akima,
              random = list(Col=~ 1, Row=~ 1, br=~ 1, bc=~ 1, Plant = pdDiag(~Week)),
              data = data)
```

After running the last code I got this message:

```
Error in lme.formula(Yield ~ Genotype + Table + Genotype:Week +  : 
  fewer observations than random effects in all level 5 groups
```

Finally, I would also like to fit a model with the same fixed and random effect, but with a repeated factor with "Week" measurements per "Col x Row xBlock".

I've been looking for a solution, but I haven't found a similar example. Could someone help me to solve it?

A solution for how to fit a repeated factor with "Plant" as the subject, for which measurements have been taken every "week". It is important to fit the UNSTRUCTURED variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: The error message sounds fairly clear. Data is too sparse for that model.

Comment: I run the same model in SAS,  and it works. I thought it was possible to run in R as well.

Comment: Data prep in SAS and R and coding of categorical variables are VERY different. I suspect it is not "the same".  You are new to SO and need to read [ask] and [MCVE].